# Nginx mime types errors. How can I set them inside a docker container?

Tags: javascript, css, nginx, webserver, static-files

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "1.0"
services:
  web:
    container_name: webserver
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./frontend:/frontend
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    environment:
      - NGINX_HOST=someweb.com
      - NGINX_PORT=80
```

The following `nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data www-data;
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name some.server;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
            root /frontend;
            index index.html;

            gzip_static on;
        }
    }
}
```

My static files inside `frontend` are the following:

```
├── assets
│   ├── index-af7a4a31.css
│   ├── index-ef3b217c.js
│   └── logo-e79ddb16.gif
├── bootstrap.min.css
├── bootstrap.min.js
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── popper.min.js
└── logo.gif
```

But I try to enter the website I get:

```
The stylesheet http://192.168.68.112:8001/bootstrap.min.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/plain”, is not “text/css”.

The stylesheet http://192.168.68.112:8001/assets/index-af7a4a31.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/plain”, is not “text/css”.

The script from “http://192.168.68.112:8001/bootstrap.min.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/plain”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
```

I would expect that by adding the `include /etc/nginx/mime.types` this would be solved but it didn't, however when I try to request the website using a browser I get the `MIME type` errors and my css doesn't load, my js does but with warnings. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` line inside the http scope, instead of the server scope?
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/